# User Properties in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

All properties return Empty Strings except for FirstName.

I can't find any errors in the code.

I tried many times but still get Empty strings. The only property that returns a value is FirstName.

```
       public static async void GetCurrenntLocalUsers
                 (ObservableCollection<UserInformation> informations )
       {
           IReadOnlyList<User> users = await 
                      Windows.System.User.FindAllAsync(UserType.LocalUser,
                      UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated);

           foreach (var user in users)
           {

               IRandomAccessStreamReference img = await 
                     user.GetPictureAsync(UserPictureSize.Size64x64);

               var stream = await img.OpenReadAsync();

               BitmapImage image=new BitmapImage();

               image.SetSource(stream);

               var userprop = await 
                     user.GetPropertiesAsync(await getproperties());

               string ff = userprop[KnownUserProperties.AccountName].ToString(); //Empty String

               informations.Add(new UserInformation()
               {
                    Name = userprop[KnownUserProperties.FirstName].ToString(),
                    DomainName = userprop[KnownUserProperties.DomainName].ToString(), //Empty String
                    UserImage = image
               });

            }
       }
```

And getProperties is

```
  private static async Task<IReadOnlyList<string>> getproperties()
  {
         var prop=new List<String>()
         {
                KnownUserProperties.FirstName,
                KnownUserProperties.DomainName,
                KnownUserProperties.AccountName
         };
         return prop;
  }
```

Comment: Without seeing where you're setting the properties I have no way of giving you an answer.

Comment: Actually i want to bind with Text block and i also give the permission in the packge.manifst file also to Access info

Comment: Okay, well then I repeat. Without seeing all of the relative code, I can't help you.

Comment: Have you permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Ref [App Capability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations)

This userAccountInformation capability is required to access some APIs in the Windows.System.UserProfile namespace. It must include the uap namespace when you declare it in your app's package manifest as shown below:

```
<Capabilities>
    <uap:Capability Name="userAccountInformation" />
  </Capabilities>
```

For local user, only the `DisplayName` property would be achieved through `User.GetPropertiesAsync()` method.

For domain user, the following properties equals the actual value:

- DisplayName: Franklin Chen
- DomainName: xxxx.domain.COM\user_alias
- FirstName: Franklin
- LastName: Chen
- SessionInitiationProtocolUri: sip://user_alias@domain.com